chart js 3.7.1 stacked bar chart tooltip hover
I'm new to chart js, studying and creating custom chart since there are some instance that i cannot achieve in data studio so I tried to do it in chartjs. but now I am stuck in achieving what i want, based in the code below, it only shows 1 data from the stacked bar even i set it to mode: 'index'. any insights what i missed or did wrong? also i searched a similar post here, and i edited the jfiddle to what i want to achieve, however when i try in my code it does not work.
here's the sample jfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/9xz0Le13/3/
thank you all
stacked bar chart hover
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" 
    integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.css" 
    integrity="sha512-C7hOmCgGzihKXzyPU/z4nv97W0d9bv4ALuuEbSf6hm93myico9qa0hv4dODThvCsqQUmKmLcJmlpRmCaApr83g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 1500px; height: 300px;" >
    <canvas id="barChart" class="chartjs-render-monitor" ></canvas>
    </div><br>
  </body>
  <script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      getData();
    });

function getData() 
    {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
      {
        var data2 = [];
        var data3 = [];
        var data4 = [];
        var data5 = [];
        var label = [];

        ar.forEach(function(item, index){ 
          label.push(item[0]);   
          data2.push(item[2]);
          data3.push(item[3]);
          data4.push(item[4]);
          data5.push(item[5]);
        });
    
        var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");

          var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
              label: 'CCM1 Values',
              data: data2,
              stack: 'Stack 0',
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: '#AF7AC5',
            },{
              label: 'CCM1 Deals',
              data: data3,
              stack: 'Stack 1',
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: '#5499C7',
            },{
              label: 'CCM+ Value',
              data: data4,
              stack: 'Stack 0',
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: '#C39BD3',
            },{
              label: 'CCM+ Deals',
              data: data5,
              stack: 'Stack 1',
              fill: true,
              backgroundColor: '#7FB3D5',
            }]
          },
          options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            elements: {
              line: {
                tension: 0.000001
              }
            },
            // Mouse Hover tooltip
            plugins:{
              tooltip: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
              }
            },
            scales: {
              x: {
                stacked: true
              },
              y: {
                position: 'left',
                stacked: true,
                  ticks: {
                    callback: 
                      function(value, index, values) {
                        return value.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"JPY"})
                      }, 
                      beginAtZero: true, 
                      suggestedMin: true, 
                      suggestedMax: true,
                  },
              }                         
            }
          }
        });
      }).getData();


In the code you posted, you are linking to chart.js version 2.9.4; your options are however corresponding to chart.js version 3+; either change the CDN link to use a v3 distribution, or change the options. In particular, tooltip options in v2.9.4 are set through options.tooltips and not options.plugins.tooltip.
